# How to animate divs when they move to fill empty space left by other divs that fade out

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a set of divs, each corresponds to a set of categories. When I click on a filter, this will change the classes of the divs and make them vissible or hidden depending on those categories. I control how the divs fade in/out and they do it slow and nicely but everytime the divs disappear the ones that are left unchanged move abruptly to fill the empty space left by the ones that were hidden.

How can I smooth the movement of the divs that weren't hidden after the other ones disappear and left an empty space?

```
 //Before this goes a long function that decides wich divs will get their class changed
 $('#work-container > div[class*=visible]').fadeIn('slow','swing');
 $('#work-container > div[class*=hidden]').fadeOut('slow','swing');
```

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Ccswn/3/ Fiddle of the thing

Comment: Do you have a demo? Or, at the very least, some representative HTML we can copy&paste *into* a demo?

Comment: plz provide a jsfiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: you want to animate them more than this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ccswn/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using `animate()` in place of `fadeOut()`:

```
$('div').click(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'height': 0,
            'opacity': 0
        }, 750, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZdpBw/).

---

**Edited** to incorporate a jQuery/CSS solution:

Change the CSS for `.item` to include the following:

```
.item{
    /* other css removed for brevity */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

And change the `a.hidden` to the following:

```
.hidden {
    width: 0; /* reset everything that might affect the size/visibility */
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

With the following jQuery:

```
// content animate
$('#work-container > div[class*=hidden]').addClass('hidden');
return false;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ccswn/7/).

And then everything seems to work as you want. Though I've not tried to follow what the `.addClass('visible')` in the block above does, but I left it alone.

This does require a browser that supports CSS transitions (and has support for `opacity`), though, so it might not be perfect in your use-case.

Comment: How should I do the reverse animation to make hidden divs show up again? if the height should be dynamic, I mean

Comment: That's similar to what `show` and `hide` does. They animate the css properties height/width/opacity etc.

Comment: @ElaineMarley: see the edits, hopefully that'll work for you.

Comment: This looks nice, also the hide/show solutions do the job on the fiddle but once I have an image inside the divs the animation will break a little. Also I don't mind much about this solution being for modern browsers only as not having this won't break functionality for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `show` and `hide` methods:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ccswn/5/

Comment: They do, but rather abruptly, I want to animate such movement.