# Smooth rearrangement of div boxes after one hides, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a list of boxes with some content.. Ive added a swipe function which hides the desired box. The problem is that, when that box hides, the one which is below goes up real quick and that doesnt look smooth at all. What I want to imitate is the smooth effect of rearrangement of boxes when a box hides because of a swipe just like Google Now Cards do. Ive done a snippet order to try to explain what I mean better.

Clicking on box 2 hides that box and box 3 goes up to replace box´s 2 place, but it goes there quick.. How do I do to make that rearrangement slower? I´d appreciate any advice you give

```js
$('.container').on('click', '#b2', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(600);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="b1">
    <h3>This is box 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="b2">
    <h3>This is box 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="b3">
    <h3>This is box 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `toggle()` instead of `fadeOut`

```
$('.container').on('click', '#b2', function() {
  $(this).toggle("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
```

fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/844h2gc4/)

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `fadeOut()` you  can use [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

```
$('.container').on('click', '#b2', function() {
  $(this).slideUp("slow", "linear", function() {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer which i think does exactly what you want:

[How to animate divs when they move to fill empty space left by other divs that fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213095/how-to-animate-divs-when-they-move-to-fill-empty-space-left-by-other-divs-that-f)

The jquery code would be like this I think:

```
$('.container').on('click', '#b2', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'height': 0,
        'opacity': 0
    }, 750, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```js
$('.container').on('click', '#b2', function() {
  $(this).fadeTo( 600, 0 );
  $(this).animate( {height: "0px"}, 600, function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px; /*Adjusted height*/
  background-color: yellow;  
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="b1">
    <h3>This is box 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="b2">
    <h3>This is box 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="b3">
    <h3>This is box 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```